# Is there a limitation on blocksize for reading when using fread in C?

Tags: c, android-ndk, fread

I am currently programming an application for smartphones using C++ and the NDK. For reading external files, I use `fread`. This works well on Windows, however, on Android phones, I got a mess with my implementation of the deflate decompressor. Of course I thought, there something wrong with my implementation of deflate, but it didn't really make sense as everything worked perfectly on Windows machines. After hours, I was finally able to track down the problem to `fread`.

I am reading a file of size 4790954 and the return value of `fread` is also 4790954. I, however discovered, that the buffer starts to contain trash at offset: 4194304. Exactly 4MB. Is there any known limitation on blocksize to be read at once that are defined in ANSI C I am not aware of?? Also, isn't that considered a bug, if the Google NDK `fread` function returns an amount of read bytes of 4790954, if it however, only read 4194304 bytes (4MB)?

Comment: Suspect #1, ANSI C, does not contain that limitation, as it uses `size_t` throughout.

Comment: There is no such limitation in C. Are you absolutely positive that the "trash" was written there by `fread()`? Unrelated memory corruption bugs can trash arbitrary portions of memory. It is not impossible that a basic function such as `fread()` is buggy on Android, but it is not very likely either, and such assertion should be accompanied by carefully collected evidence.

Comment: Its not my intention to assert anything bad related to the sacred google fread function. ;-) I was trying to make sure I didn't overlook something obvious before I dig deeper into the rabbit hole ;-)

Comment: Can you show your `fread` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its quite some time ago but looking around my profile I realized that this question remained open even though I found a solution to the problem a long time aog. The error was rather stupid - I didn't open the file in binary mode using fopen, which led to this strange behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limitation on blocksize for reading when using fread in C?

Not *per se*. The limitation is implied based on the data types. Android is 32-bit only, so `size_t` is 32-bits. There's also a potential for wrap leading to a smaller read size because of `object_size * number_of_objects` (these are unsigned values, so they wrap rather than overflow).

From [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) and [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html):

```
size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,
       FILE *restrict stream);
```

And the description:

> The `fread()` function shall read into the array pointed to by `ptr` up to
>   `nitems` elements whose size is specified by size in bytes, from the
>   stream pointed to by stream. For each object, size calls shall be made
>   to the `fgetc()` function and the results stored, in the order read, in
>   an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object.

What does `ferror(fp)` return after the read? Is there an error?

Related: you might want to have a quick look at the answer of [Using fread properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796037/608639). I'm not claiming there's a problem in your usage fo `fread` or `fgetc`. But there's no code, so we can't tell.